# For who or what was Cojo Creek named?

Tags: colonial-america, california, spanish-empire, toponymy

Cojo Creek (Cañada del cojo) is the boundary between the Rancho Punta de la Concepción and the Rancho Nuestra Señora del Refugio. The anchorage at the mouth of this creek was a prime smuggling spot in the Spanish era.

*Cojo* means lame, in the sense of having a bum leg or being an amputee.

For who or what was the creek named?

[image: Map of old and new fences along Cojo Creek between Rancho Punta de la Concepcion and Rancho Nuestra Señora del Refugio : Calif.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cojo Creek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rancho_Punta_de_la_Concepcion) was named for the lame chief of the Chumash Indian tribe, the first people that the Spanish met near what is now the Rancho Punta de la Concepción in August 1769.

Comment: A nine minute turnaround is pretty impressive. Well done.